# cURL PHP Upload Issues

Tags: php, curl, upload

I'm trying to make a plain cURL upload to hugefiles.net, but with no luck.

I have set the $data['srv_tmp_url'] manually, (hope that it can be done so) and also the upload_id parametar, to avoid any page scraping for now.

When the script executes It does redirect me to a download link, but the file on that link there only contains about 25 B.
Here is the code, hope someone can try this and point out the mistakes I am making, thanks.

```html
<?php

function Upload_curl($url,$data)
{


        $ch = curl_init();


        
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 1000);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,FALSE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://hugefiles.net/");




        $result = curl_exec($ch);    
        return $result;


}
$filename = "test.rar";
$data = array();
$data['upload_type'] = "file";
$data['srv_tmp_url'] = "http://us02.hugefiles.net/tmp";
$data['file_0; filename="'.$filename.'"'] = "@C:/xampp/htdocs/test.rar";
//$data["sess_id"] = "";



echo Upload_curl("http://us02.hugefiles.net/cgi-bin/upload.cgi?upload_id=310423971419&js_on=1&utype=&upload_type=file",$data);


?>
```

Comment: What does the 25-byte file contain? Chances are it's an error message that will help you find the problem

Comment: You don't seem to be doing any debugging, for example using curl_error(), definitely add that http://php.net/curl_error

Comment: The file is corrupted and can't be opened.I tried with curl_error(), but no errors were returned.

Comment: Open it with a text editor

Comment: Actually now that i have opened it with notepad it contains this string "@C:/xampp/htdocs/test.rar", the path of the file that I was trying to upload.I dont know what it means.